# Suspicious Squares and Magnitudes of Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

**Problem:**
Let $z_1,$ $z_2,$ $z_3$ be complex numbers such that $|z_1| = 1,$ $|z_2| = 2,$ $|z_3| = 3,$ and
$$|9z_1 z_2 + 4z_1 z_3 + z_2 z_3| = 12.$$Find $|z_1 + z_2 + z_3|.$

**Progress:**
I received this problem yesterday as a challenge, but I cannot seem to find the answer. I know that brute-forcing my way through will probably be impossible, as it gets really messy really quickly. I am noticing that if I square the magnitude equations, I get $z_1\overline{z_1}=1$, $z_2\overline{z_2}=4$, and $z_3\overline{z_3}=9$, the coefficients of the long equation, hence why the title is as it is. From here, however, I am not sure how to continue, can somebody please give a solution explaining your steps? Thanks! (I'm new to this, so if I'm doing anything wrong, please let me know as well.)

Comment: Hint: divide the given relation by $|z_1z_2z_3|$ and use that $\,1/z_1 = \bar z_1, \,4/z_2=\bar z_2, \,9/z_3=\bar z_3\,$.

Comment: Wow nice find, from there its easy to see by simple identities that the answer is 12/6=2.